# How do I check if something is a letter or not?

Tags: python, input, letter

I want to check if the information someone has inputted is a letter or not

```py
a=input("Input one letter: ")
#This doesn't actually work
if a==letter:
  print("wow u inputted a letter")
else:
  print("not a letter")
```

also, I don't want to have to make 26 if statements

Comment: Try `a.isalpha()`

Comment: @MichaelHodel - that will give `True` for `'abc'` - I think OP wants only one letter strings to pass. `a.isalpha() and len(a) == 1` would work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a constant called `ascii_letters` in the [string library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html):

```py
from string import ascii_letters # 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

a = input("Input one letter: ")
if a in list(ascii_letters): # Convert to list so that each element is one character
    print('This is a letter')
else:
    print('This is not a letter')
```

For lowercase, use `string.ascii_lowercase`, and for uppercase, use `string.ascii_uppercase`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use python's built-in functions [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalpha#str.isalpha) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) combined like so:

```py
a.isalpha() and len(a) == 1
```